# Linking CSS file to masterpage

Tags: cssregistration

I'm trying to link my custom CSS file to the MasterPage and I want all sites that exist/not created to use that masterpage.
 Is this possible? do I need to turn on any site collection features or site features?

Comment: what problem are you facing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you tiring to add your link?

anyway, you can add the link to the master page, and publish it, then go to  site settings > Master Page > and select the master page